# Localization with ASP.NET MVC using Application_Start to CurrentUiCulture doesn't seem to work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have written a small asp.net mvc 3 app and my UI doesn't seem to be changing i have this set in the Application_Start but it never works.

```
        const string culture = "en-US";
        CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(culture);

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
```

But if i set the same in the Initialize method of a controller then it works.

But i don't want to override all controllers.

Does it not work form Applicaiton_Start?

I have set a breakpoint and i can see it passing through it.

but in my views i do

```
   @Index.Test
```

And if set via Application_Start then i always got a non english version (the default in my case)

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`Application_Start` will be called only once. You have to set that in the `Application_BeginRequest` event.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below settings in config file under

globalization culture="auto:DefaultCulture" uiculture="auto:DefaultCulture"